# Getting started and having trouble with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I decided to try to my hand at this, and have had a somewhat frustrating day.  I've been downloading and installing all the developement software, but Eclipse has given me lots of trouble.  I've figured most of it out, but have another problem.  For some reason the Google APIs are not installing :

[image]

[bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79bEa.png)

Why is this?  They are important right?  I'm currently using a book for total beginners, and I pretty much have no idea what I'm doing as of now.  Thank you SO MUCH for any help and your time viewing this.

(I am running Eclipse Indigo)

Comment: Don't mind them just skip it. They are not compatible with your windows and you will problem don't need them.

Comment: They aren't needed to test apps on them or anything of the sort?  The Google TV isn't compatitable, but I believe the APIs are, for some reason they just aren't installing.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the status bar, they are installing fine. Just the *Google TV* is not compatible with your environment. If you want to go for smartphone app development, then either the "pure" Android APIs or the Google APIs (including Google Maps) are fine for the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, should have taken another picture.  Actually this is my 4th time trying to install them, and they didn't install after the status bar was filled.

Comment: Ok, try installing just one of the API levels. I have seen the installation fail (especially the unzipping part) when installing lots of them in a batch. And check that your disk has enough space and your RAM is not at its limits for the unzipping operation.

Comment: Hmmm.  It says file not found, I used http://dl-ssl.google/android/eclipse as the software site.  I'm going totally off of a book I bought for beginners, so when things deviate from the book, or don't work out as shown, it takes me a bit to work things out.  Phew!  The "Google USB driver" also didn't install, I would use that later to test the app on my phone, correct?  That seems important, do you think I can just pass this stuff and move on, or will I need it later? 

Thank you so much for your time and patience.  If you lived closer I'd buy you a beer.

Comment: If the file is not there after the download, I would suspect an anti virus program to be over cautious and to lock/protect/quarantine the file for whatever reasons. Your URL is right, as you can see on the (more up to date than your book maybe) Android developer web site http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Ahhh...that could be it!  It's 3 am here (S. Korea)..time for bed.  Thanks a lot of your help, I'll try turning off the anti-virus first thing in the morning.  I can't click useful answer yet because I don't have enough reputation, but I owe you one for your time.

Comment: And last but not least: You are trying to install your downloaded API levels in the %PROGRAMSFOLDER%, which is protected by Windows. You may want to try just moving the unzipped SDK itself to another location on disk, changing it afterwards in the Eclipse Android preferences and then run the API installation again.

Comment: Your last suggestion was it!  I moved it to the desktop and am downloading and installing them now!  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Google APIs aren't 100% mission critical to developing an Android application, but do contain classes and methods for using most of the Google features (Gmail, Google Maps, etc.).

You should be fine with just the Android APIs until you get into the more advanced functionality of the platform.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.  May I ask another question?  What is the difference between Google APIs and Android APIs?  Do I already have the Android APIs?  Sorry if this is a ridiculously noobish question, I am a total begginner.  Really appreciate any help!  Also...the "Google USB driver" is not installing, this is fairly important right?  In my book, it shows up in the next step :(

Comment: The android API's are the core apis, everything you need for android is there.The google api's are api's for google services.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a lot for your help.  I'm sorry to bug you, but one last question.  The "Google USB Driver" is also not installing, the usb driver is used to connect my computer to my phone and allow them to interact to test an app, correct?  Will I need this Google USB Driver later?  Thanks again sooo much

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on the function of that Driver, but I think that's only needed if you wanted to mess around with how you'd be loading or offloading files or other items off of your device. I wouldn't worry about it too much if you're just beginning Android development.